# Brun's paper on convergent sum of reciprocals of twin primes

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, twin-primes

Does anyone know where I can find a PDF (or equivalent) of Brun's 1919 paper (linked to in the references [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrunsConstant.html), but with a title too messy to write out in full on this forum) that proved that the sum of the reciprocals of all twin primes converge to a constant $B_2$?

I'm not at university and have no access to the standard online math journals. (MathSciNet thinks it's reasonable to charge amateurs who are just trying to learn $9,000 for a year's access. Disgusting...)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k486270d/f138.item.r=brun) is a link to the article on the Gallica website. Note that many ''sufficiently old'' research papers can be found there in a scanned format.

Comment: Hi @Klangen. Wow, many thanks. That's a scan from quite a way back by the look of it! But it has what I need. Really grateful.